# Error when trying to load lazily loaded component from external bundle

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

I wanted to mix webpack externals and React's lazy load to optmize my builds.

Summary of my setup looks like this:

**shared-ui-components** -> is a npm module with React components, its build output goes to s3 bucket so that main app can use.

This is achieved following output config in webpack

```
  output: {
    //...
    library: 'SUIC',
  }
```

and

**Main App** -> uses shared-ui-components

This is achieved following output config in webpack

```
  externals: {
    "shared-ui-components": "SUIC"
  }
```

and linking the scripts tags to bucket uri to include `shared-ui-components` built output.

This is all working great.

Next, since there are multiple big components in `shared-ui-components`,
I want to lazily load some of the components and use chunks.

An example snippet:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { lazy, Suspense } from 'react';

const Feed = lazy(() => import('../Feed/Feed'));

const LoadableFeed = () => {
  return <div className="central-comp">
    <Suspense fallback={<p>Loading feed…</p>}>
      <Feed />
    </Suspense>
  </div>
}

export default LoadableFeed
```

I am using following `tsconfig` in both projects:

```
 "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  }
```

The `shared-ui-components` build seems to be producing proper chunks.

Now, when I use `Feed` in main app,

```
import { LoadableFeed } from 'shared-ui-components';

const CentralContent = () => {
  return <div className="central-comp">
    <h4>Central Content</h4>
    <LoadableFeed />
  </div>
}

export default CentralContent
```

I can see the bundle js from `shared-ui-components` can load the chunks needed, but it cannot render the component.

The error message says 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined at o`

and `react-dom.development.js:17252 The above error occurred in one of your React components: in Unknown (created by c)`, where `c` I found refers to `LoadableFeed`

Seems like the main app's bundle cannot render the lazily loaded components bundle defined in `shared-ui-components` or the lazily loaded component itself cannot render when used elsewhere.

Is there a way we can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by setting `module` to `commonjs` in `tsconfig` of the main app.
Makes sense that the final app build output should use `commonjs` instead of `esnext`